# What is the default Amazon EMR hive password?

Tags: hive, amazon-emr

I'm connecting to an Amazon EMR hivethriftserver2. I always got this information:

Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:****:10000: Peer indicated failure: Error validating the login

What is the right password to validate the login?

Answer (score 1):

Empty

Username : ''
Password : ''.

However, if you are planning on running map-reduce jobs remotely, use the following configuration :-
Username : hadoop
Password : ''